# Passing parameter in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create smooth scrolling in my page, but I have problem with passing parameters in JQuery. I would like to get the position of the divs. I tried something like that but it does not work for me.

Thanks for help

```
function myFunction(el) {
   var $el = $(el).offset().top;
   console.log($el);
}

<li><a href="#" onclick="myFunction('home-content')" >Main</a></li>
```

Comment: what is `home-content`?

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Comment: *"does not work"* is not a useful description of the problem.

Comment: how is the code in the question related to "smooth scrolling"?

Comment: If you're passing a `string` as parameter, why do you concatenate `'.'` instead of just passing `.home-content`?

Comment: Home-content is a class name of the div from which I want to know offset().top value..

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/rez93z02/

Comment: That code should work so we need more context...

Comment: `passing parameters in JQuery` ... the only jQuery parameter in your code will be `.home-content` - this will result in `$el` being a jQuery object that has all elements whose class includes `home-content` - which part of that doesn't work for you

Comment: This code works, just doesn't do what you described because what you wrote is console.log instead of some offset manipulation

Comment: "home-content" is not valid selector. Use onclick="myFunction('.home-content') if it's a class, or onclick="myFunction('#home-content') if it's an ID, to get what you want

Comment: OK, I corrected my code. Now it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery selector (passed as a parameter to *myFunction(el)*) is wrong. Attach valid prefix to your selector, ie.:

```
   <li><a href="#" onclick="myFunction('.home-content')" >Main</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

while calling function myFunction you should mention the element either with class or element type use #home-content or .home-content instead as a parameter.